# Swift how to create a protocol delegate from root VC to embedded VC

Tags: ios, swift

I have a root VC that embeds a table view through a container view with segue. So that makes both the root VC and child VC visible at the same time.

```
 if segue.identifier == "TableSegue" {
            let toView = segue.destinationViewController as! TableViewController
            toView.delegate = self
        }
```

How can I implement a protocol delegate between the root vc and child vc since the child VC is embedded inside the root vc?

What I want to do is to have a functions fired in the child VC once a button in root VC is clicked.

I have tried to implement a protocol delegate the normal way but it seems to not be picked up in the child VC

Answer (score 0):

```
protocol TableViewInterface {
   func someWork()
}

class RootVC:UIViewController {
    var delegate: TableViewInterface?

    func callDelegate() {
       delegate?.someWork()
    }

}

class TableViewController: UITableViewController, TableViewInterface {

    func someWork() {
      //Perform your the work you want done or the action you want fired in your tableView here...
    }
}
```

The above is an example of a standard delegate pattern in swift. It looks like you are trying to set the delegate in prepareForSegue(), but IRRC it won't get called with a containerView. You probably want to get a reference to you tableView through your container view.

You should be able to get a reference to it by doing something like this in your RootVC

```
if let tableVC = childViewControllers[0] as? TableViewController {
            self.tableViewController = tableVC
}
```

I hope this all makes sense